# Show that a Banach space with certain assumptions must be finite dimensional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ its dual. Suppose that there is a sequence of $L_n \in X^*$ satisfying the following property: any sequence $x_j, x \in X$ converges weakly iff $L_n(x_j) \rightarrow L_n(x)$ for all $n$. Show that $X$ is finite dimensional (hint: consider $d(x, y) = \sum_{n} 2^{-n}\frac{|L_n(x-y)|}{1 + |L_n(x-y)|}$).

To prove this, I want to use the following theorem:

> Any infinite dimensional Banach space endowed with the weak topology cannot be homeomorphic to a complete metric space.

So, I am trying to show that

1. $(X, d)$ is a complete metric space
2. $X$ equipped with the weak topology is homeomorphic to $X$ with the metric topology given by $d$.

which I need some helps.
I know that there is a stronger version of the theorem I mentioned above (i.e. infinite dimensional Banach space with the weak topology is not metrizable), so using this fact, it would suffices to show that 2. But, I would like to see how to prove 1 if it is indeed true.

Comment: For 1.&2., see e.g. section about LCS in John B. Conway’s book *A Course in Functional Analysis*, GTM96. A complete picture is: such $L_n$’s define a series of seminorms and hence define a locally compact space, which turns out to have the topology identical to that one generated by the metric $d$.

Comment: Any separable Banach space $X$ with a separable dual $X^*$ satisfies your condition, e.g., $\ell^p$ spaces. You should replace "sequence"s with "net"s to conclude that $X$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @OnurOktay $\ell^p$ also admits weakly convergent sequences that are not norm convergent.

Comment: @s.harp $\ell^p$ doesn't have Schur property for $p>1$, but the question is not about this.

Comment: @OnurOktay the existence of a sequence weakly convergent to say $0$ implies that $L_n(x_j)\to0$ for all $n$. If the sequence doesn't converge in norm then the property of the question clearly doesn't hold.

Comment: @s.harp Why not? Suppose both $X$ and $X^*$ are separable. Let $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a dense subset of $X^*$. It is not difficult to show that a sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is weakly null iff $f_n(x_i)\to 0$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Yet, this doesn't imply that $\|x_n\|\to 0$. For example, take $X=\ell^p$ for $1<p<\infty$. The set of all sequences that is zero for all but finitely many terms with rational entries, is dense in $\ell^q$.

Comment: @OnurOktay I see, OP has transcribed his problem incorrectly. The question I had read/interpreted initially was that $x_j\to x$ in **norm** $\iff$ $L_n(x_j)\to L_n(x)$ for all $n$. This is indeed equivalent to finite dimensional. The version as it is written is false, as you remark correctly.

Comment: @OnurOktay Thanks for your comment. You mentioned that if $X^*$ is separable, then the condition is satisfied. Would you be able to provide a rough proof of this? I can easily show this assuming that a sequence is norm-bounded, but not for general sequences.

Comment: @Luke Every weakly convergent sequence is norm bounded. On a related note, weakly convergent nets may not be norm bounded.